# Procesar multiples mensajes de ActiveMQ en multiples consumidores

Tags: c#, apache

Cuando envio 3 mensajes a una cola de ActiveMQ, si tengo dos consumidores automaticamente se asignan dos mensajes a un consumidor y uno a otro consumidor... entonces si quiere obtener los 3 mensajes de un consumidor no puedo.

Hay alguna forma de poder obtener los mensajes enviados a una cola, desde un consumidor u otro indistintamente, sin que haya ningun tipo de preasignación?

Gracias.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta en ingles.

Comment: perdona pensaba que estaba en la versión angloparlante de stackoverflow, ya lo he corregido

Answer (score 0):

Partamos de la base que las queus no tienen ningun tipo de preasignacion

[Introducción a Apache ActiveMQ](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/active-mq/)

veras que comenta

> Nuestro consumidor procesará los todos mensajes que haya en la cola “a demanda” (cuando se ejecute). Si quisiésemos que procesase cada mensaje cuando llega a la cola (no es nuestro caso) deberíamos implementar la interface javax.jms.MessageListener y lanzar nuestro proceso como un hilo que se queda en espera (Thread).

entiendo no estas usando java, pero el equivalente en c# seria el

[Asynchronous consumption](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/examples.html)

asignando un evento en el `Listener`

```
using(IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination))
using(IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination))
{
    // Start the connection so that messages will be processed.
    connection.Start();
    producer.Persistent = true;
    producer.RequestTimeout = receiveTimeout;
    consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(OnMessage);

    //resto codigo
```

el tema es que en tu caso tendras dos consumidores con lo cual requieres de un balanceo de carga que permita distribuir los mensajes

Quizas debas evaluar 
[Clustering](http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html)

Comment: El balanceo de carga lo gestiono yo, en el caso de este ejemplo quiero que el consumidor A consuma todos los elementos que hay en la cola en ese momento.... pero por alguna razón solo me deja consumir 2 de los 3 elementos. El tercer elemento solo me deja consumirlo con el consumer B, es por ello que he presupuesto que hay una preasignacion automatica de los mensajes en los distintos consumers antes de consumirlos... si no es asi no entiendo por que mi consumer A no solo puede consumir los 3 primeros elementos y no el tercero.

Comment: si ambos consumer estan activos podria tomarlo el primero que se libera, si solo dejas ejecutando el consumidor A este toma todos los mensajes? si solo dejas eejcutando el consumidor B este toma todos los mensajes?